# JDBC in Jython, prepared statements

Tags: jdbc, jython, jython-2.5

I am looking arround for prepared statements in **Jython** with **JDBC** (**zxJDBC**) / SQLite.
All I find is examples like this ([book](http://books.google.de/books?id=eoPGiDflrtkC&pg=PA243&lpg=PA243&dq=jython+jdbc+preparedstatement&source=bl&ots=i-9u5yVS_v&sig=JxM1RKMnGXXfrdmainjFEkddi_c&hl=de&sa=X&ei=fi7HT5TeAvPO4QSZpeGrDg&sqi=2&ved=0CGwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=jython%20jdbc%20preparedstatement&f=false), [Jython documentation](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/DatabasesAndJython.html#prepared-statements)):

```
qry = "select continent from country where name = ?"
cursor.executemany(qry,['Austria'])
```

However I always understood prepared statements as a way to let the Database optimize a statement without knowing the values inserted for the placeholders. One then receives a handle to this statement wich has been passed through the optimizer and can execute this with different values, saving the query optimization effort, thus I would expect that the following approach is better:

```
qry = cursor.prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field`=? AND `field2`=?") #usually mor complex queries
qry.execute(cursor, ?, (val1, val2)??) #here is the problem
```

unfortunately I can't find examples of how to use the execute and the documentation is lacking.

```
PyStatement.execute(cursor, params, bindings)
```

Could you explain me what `params` is for and if my guess at how to use `bindings` is correct. My best guess for params would be, that they are the first parameter to the `setInt`-Method (or the like) from Javas JDBC, put that would be rather surprising. I expected to be Jython more short handed and for it to simply expect the parameters in the right(front to back) order.

**Bonus**: Is there a way to free a resultset? (Besides closing the cursor)

Comment: Not an answer (because I don't know jython), but the first call probably just prepares the statement, binds the parameters and execute the query in one go. prepared statements is not only to execute several similar queries. It's also useful to make the driver escape the parameters properly, and prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: not an answer since i need the second case(multiple times the same query), but insightfull non the less

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this extension uses the normal [Python Database Specification v2](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)

For `execute` it says:

> A reference to the operation will be retained by the cursor. If the same operation object is passed in again, then the cursor can optimize its behavior. This is most effective for algorithms where the same operation is used, but different parameters are bound to it (many times).

And for `executemany` it says:

> The same comments as for .execute() also apply accordingly to this method.

So if this drivers actually implements these suggested semantics, then just passing in the same string into `execute` or `executemany` should reuse the preparedstatement, however you might want to check the implementation (or ask the implementer) to be sure

Comment: very informative, I still hope though that someone cna shine a light on the use of prepare, even if it just creates a lambda function that binds `execute` I like the look better to simply store an object in my class, instead of a string